# What happens inside beamerposter and theorem environment

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

If I compile

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[scale=4]{beamerposter}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{
  {\color{blue}\inserttheoremheadfont% \bfseries
  \inserttheoremname
  \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
  :} \normalfont
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
qqq
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

theorembody is normal.
But, if I compile with beamerposter

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=4]{beamerposter}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{
  {\color{blue}\inserttheoremheadfont% \bfseries
  \inserttheoremname
  \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
  :} \normalfont
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
qqq
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

theorembody is italic!
Why, and how repair it?

Answer (score 1):

As a quick hack to get upright font:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=4]{beamerposter}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{
  {\color{blue}\inserttheoremheadfont% \bfseries
  \inserttheoremname
  \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
  :} \normalfont\upshape
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
qqq
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```